# Trouble understanding why multimeter gives different resistance readings

Tags: resistance, multimeter, ohmmeter

I want to preface this by I am a hobby electronics guy with some experience from reading *The Art of Electronics*. I know how to use a multimeter but I am very confused at what I am seeing.

I am using a marginally more expensive Circuit Specialists multimeter and testing the resistance across a set of fuel injectors I am working on. My procedure to test is as follows:

1. Set multimeter to Ohms (200)
2. Measure resistance across the male side plugs

I was looking for a reference range of 10-14 ohms and I got 15.3 ohms. Concerning. So out of curiosity I measured again:

1. Set the mulimeter to Kilohms (2k ohms)
2. Measure the resistance across the male side plugs.

However this time I got 0.012! So 12 ohms, right in the middle of the range.

It may be as simple as my multimeter just isn't very high quality but I was hoping there was a better explanation. Having one measurement outside spec, and one inside spec really bothers me.

EDIT:

My multimeter model is #MT-5211

https://www.circuitspecialists.com/3-1-2-digital-lcr-multimeter.html

Comment: What is the multimeter make and model? Link to datasheets and specifications? What kind of multimeter leads you used?

Comment: Any measuring instrument suffers a bit from this.  THe bigger the range, the less absolute precision you get.  It's best to measure with the smallest range that fits your expected values.   If you have it on the 1,000,000 ohm range, you might see "0 ohms" as a result.  DOes that mean it's actually zero?  Nope!   Just means on the 1MEG range, the meter can't report things out to such a fine precision.

Comment: If this is a digital multimeter (which I assume it is), you may be seeing the error in the ADC. You'll have more accurate results picking the smallest measurement range that your tested device fits in. If you let us know the make/model, we can look up the accuracy.

Comment: I would consider the 15.3 Ohm reading as acceptable.  At such low resistance, the resistance o fthe meter leads and your connections to the injector can easily add a couple of ohms to the reading.

Comment: BTW I wouldn't call Circuit Specialists multimeters "high end", my Fluke Processmeter costs over $1,000 and comes with a certificate of calibration/accuracy.

Comment: BTW, also when you're trying to measure like 1-2 ohms  (your example of 14 = 15.3), it's pretty tricky to do with a standard multimeter.  There is resistance in the probe tips, maybe a little oxidation on the component leads, etc.   You have to really make a solid connection.  Sometimes I'll use needle-sharp probes to poke through the outer layers and expose fresh metal.   When you start getting up to maybe 50-ohms, then your results should be just about "right".

Comment: A bit of an analogy: Take a 25' tape measure which has increments of 1/8". Measure something several inches long from a few inches away, and you will get a pretty good visual reading down to the nearest 1/8". Pull the tape measure out all 25'. Put the same object next to it. Walk far enough away that you can see the entire tape measure. You can still see the tape measure and the markings and the object you are measuring, but you'll be lucky to get to even the nearest inch.

Comment: Thank you for all the replies. I will update my post. The model number is #MT-5211 @Justme. I understand that it is not a fluke. It's certainly still budget but more expensive than the old one I had. I misspoke.

Comment: @CL40 Due to the capitalization, I was under the impression that you had a multimeter which was meant for people who are circuit specialists, not that it was bought from an online shop called Circuit Specialists.

Comment: @CL40 From the [MT-5211 manual](https://www.circuitspecialists.com/content/302297/MT-5211.pdf) it says *"At 200Ω range, the test leads should be short-circuited, and measure the lead to lead resistance, then, subtract from the real measurement"*. Did you do that?

Comment: @RonBeyer Ah! That seemed to make the measurements make sense again. There was also a temperature component I was not considering (reference ranges are for 68 F). After bringing the injectors to ~74 degrees and subtracting the error I got a value that makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Since no one in the comments posted an answer I will post it here.

First:

My multimeter is not the best multimeter. According to the manual I need to short circuit the probes and record the result for the 200 ohm setting. After taking a measurement I subtract this from the observed value to get the answer.

Second:

The specifications had temperature in a little box next to the resistance tolerances I looked over. Since resistance and temperature are related this was important.

By doing the short circuit and then letting the fuel injectors cool down to ~70 degrees I was able to achieve a reading that was within specification.

I appreciate everyone's help!